# How can I retrieve the body of a 300 Multiple Choice status?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am making a GET request to an API that returns JSON. The response is usually JSON with a status 200. However, in rare cases it returns a status 300 with JSON. That 300 response gets caught in my React app as a ResponseError.

I am able to see the contents of the body in the network tab, and `console.log(e.response.body)` shows that it's a ReadableStream, but `e.response.body.json()` throws a TypeError.

The 200 status returns an object like:

```
{
  user: { ... }
}
```

The 300 status returns an object like the following that can only be seen in the network tab:

```
{
  users: {
    user1: { ... },
    user2: { ... }
}
```

How can I access the contents of the response body in my React app? The GET is made with `fetch`. Here's a simple example of what's happening:

```
  try {
    const res = await fetch('/api/user')
    const data = await res.json()
    // status 200 always works
  } catch(e) {
    // 300 status always goes here 
    // e.response.body is a ReadableStream 
    const await res = e.response.body.json() // throws a TypeError 
  }
```

In the catch block, I tried `e.response.body.json()`. That throws a TypeError.

Comment: [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/300): "As there is no standardized way of choosing one of the responses, this response code is very rarely used." - the only thing you can do is inspect any `Location:` headers, and there might be more than 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid try catch block and use fetch API only as

```
  fetch('/api/user')
        .then((response) => {
           if(response.status == 300 || response.status == 200){
             return res.json()
           }
        })
        .then((data) => console.log(data))
        .catch((error) => {
           console.error('Error:', error);
         });
```